# JHipster 6.0.1 docker-compose deployment: Java heap space

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, jhipster, jib

I have 2 applications. App 1 is using JHipster 5.8.2 which I deploy to a Digital Ocean's droplet with 2GB RAM and, after pushing my image to gitlab's registry, I run it `docker-compose -f app.yml up` (which has `_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m`) and everything runs perfect in about 45 seconds.

App 2 was generated with JHipster 6.0.1 (it's actually an upgrade of my App 1). I used a similar droplet from App 1 for my App 2: single core with 2GB RAM but it failed because of `Java Heap Space`. After this I changed my droplet to 4GB 2 core droplet and changed my `app.yml` config to this: `_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx3072m -Xms2048m` but it still fails with the same issue and after 40 minutes.

After this error I tried running the image in my computer with 32GB, after 2 1/2 hours, the same issue arose.

This is how I packed my 6.0.1 app:

- `/mvnw verify -Pprod -DskipTests`
- `./mvnw jib:build -Dimage=registry.gitlab.com/amatos/project`

In my droplet:

- `docker-compose -f app.yml up -d`

This should work, but it never passes the line `Web application fully configured` and after several minutes (depending on the amount of RAM), it fails.

Is there an extra step I'm missing?

### FINDING:

After doing a lot of testing, I discovered that, by adding a custom DTO I get the Java heap space issue.

## Generated DTO:

```java
package com.facturapp.service.dto;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.Lob;

/**
 * A DTO for the {@link com.facturapp.domain.Address} entity.
 */
public class AddressDTO implements Serializable {

    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    private String contact;

    private String mobile;

    private String address;

    @Lob
    private String note;

    private Boolean delivery;

    private Boolean invoicing;

    private Boolean active;


    private Long districtId;

    private String districtName;

    private Long partnerId;

    private String partnerName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public Boolean isDelivery() {
        return delivery;
    }

    public void setDelivery(Boolean delivery) {
        this.delivery = delivery;
    }

    public Boolean isInvoicing() {
        return invoicing;
    }

    public void setInvoicing(Boolean invoicing) {
        this.invoicing = invoicing;
    }

    public Boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Long getDistrictId() {
        return districtId;
    }

    public void setDistrictId(Long districtId) {
        this.districtId = districtId;
    }

    public String getDistrictName() {
        return districtName;
    }

    public void setDistrictName(String districtName) {
        this.districtName = districtName;
    }

    public Long getPartnerId() {
        return partnerId;
    }

    public void setPartnerId(Long partnerId) {
        this.partnerId = partnerId;
    }

    public String getPartnerName() {
        return partnerName;
    }

    public void setPartnerName(String partnerName) {
        this.partnerName = partnerName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        AddressDTO addressDTO = (AddressDTO) o;
        if (addressDTO.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getId(), addressDTO.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AddressDTO{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", name='" + getName() + "'" +
            ", contact='" + getContact() + "'" +
            ", mobile='" + getMobile() + "'" +
            ", address='" + getAddress() + "'" +
            ", note='" + getNote() + "'" +
            ", delivery='" + isDelivery() + "'" +
            ", invoicing='" + isInvoicing() + "'" +
            ", active='" + isActive() + "'" +
            ", district=" + getDistrictId() +
            ", district='" + getDistrictName() + "'" +
            ", partner=" + getPartnerId() +
            ", partner='" + getPartnerName() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

## Custom DTO

```java
package com.facturapp.service.dto;

import com.facturapp.domain.District;

/**
 * A DTO for the {@link com.facturapp.domain.Address} entity.
 */
public class AddressFaDTO extends AddressDTO {

    private District district;

    public District getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }

    public void setDistrict(District district) {
        this.district = district;
    }
}
```

The custom DTO is `Address` and extends the generated DTO. The generated DTO has a few fields, 2 of them are `districtId (Long)` and `districtName (String)`, but my custom DTO also has `district (District)`. The class `District` has a property `Province` which also has `Region`, which also has `Country`. So when I retrieve an `Address` I also get the district, province, region and country.

My custom Resource calls a custom service that retrieves my custom DTO with the district and all the other classes.

If I use the generated DTO I have no issue, but when I use my custom DTO, the app doesn't run and fails due to the Java Heap space.

## Error logs

```
facturapp_1  | 2019-06-03 06:56:20.395  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.almasoft.facturapp.FacturApp         : Starting FacturApp on c40efbe18b21 with PID 1 (/app/classes started by root in /)
facturapp_1  | 2019-06-03 06:56:20.407  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] com.almasoft.facturapp.FacturApp         : The following profiles are active: prod,swagger
facturapp_1  | 2019-06-03 06:56:45.918  WARN 1 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Warning, Liquibase took more than 5 seconds to start up!
facturapp_1  | 2019-06-03 06:56:57.351  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.facturapp.config.WebConfigurer       : Web application configuration, using profiles: prod
facturapp_1  | 2019-06-03 06:56:57.353  INFO 1 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.facturapp.config.WebConfigurer       : Web application fully configured
facturapp_1  | WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
facturapp_1  | WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/app/libs/spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
facturapp_1  | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils
facturapp_1  | WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
facturapp_1  | WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
facturapp_1  | 2019-06-03 07:03:27.207  WARN 1 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
facturapp_1  | 2019-06-03 07:03:27.606 ERROR 1 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
facturapp_1  |
facturapp_1  | org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
facturapp_1  |  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185)
facturapp_1  |  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
facturapp_1  |  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
facturapp_1  |  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
facturapp_1  |  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
facturapp_1  |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:893)
facturapp_1  |  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)
facturapp_1  |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
facturapp_1  |  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
facturapp_1  |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
facturapp_1  |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
facturapp_1  |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
facturapp_1  |  at com.facturapp.FacturApp.main(FacturApp.java:63)
facturapp_1  |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
facturapp_1  |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
facturapp_1  |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
facturapp_1  |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
facturapp_1  |  at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
facturapp_1  | Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
facturapp_1  |  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2049)
facturapp_1  |  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
facturapp_1  |  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3976)
facturapp_1  |  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4960)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.CachingModelDependencyProvider.dependentModels(CachingModelDependencyProvider.java:58)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelProvider.dependencies(DefaultModelProvider.java:128)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.CachingModelProvider.dependencies(CachingModelProvider.java:68)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiModelReader.populateDependencies(ApiModelReader.java:136)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiModelReader.read(ApiModelReader.java:78)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiListingScanner.scan(ApiListingScanner.java:133)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiDocumentationScanner.scan(ApiDocumentationScanner.java:71)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.scanDocumentation(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:101)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:167)
facturapp_1  |  at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
facturapp_1  |  ... 17 common frames omitted
facturapp_1  | Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
facturapp_1  |  at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
facturapp_1  |  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source)
facturapp_1  |  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.addAll(Unknown Source)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedPropertiesAndFields(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:181)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedDependencies(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:120)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.maybeFromRegularType(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:207)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedPropertiesAndFields(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:183)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedDependencies(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:120)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.maybeFromRegularType(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:207)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedPropertiesAndFields(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:183)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedDependencies(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:120)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.maybeFromCollectionElementType(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:220)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedPropertiesAndFields(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:181)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedDependencies(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:120)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.maybeFromCollectionElementType(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:220)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedPropertiesAndFields(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:181)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedDependencies(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:120)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.maybeFromCollectionElementType(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:220)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedPropertiesAndFields(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:181)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedDependencies(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:120)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.maybeFromRegularType(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:207)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedPropertiesAndFields(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:183)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedDependencies(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:120)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.dependentModels(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:79)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.CachingModelDependencyProvider$1.load(CachingModelDependencyProvider.java:50)
facturapp_1  |  at springfox.documentation.schema.CachingModelDependencyProvider$1.load(CachingModelDependencyProvider.java:48)
facturapp_1  |  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529)
facturapp_1  |  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278)
facturapp_1  |  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155)
facturapp_1  |  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
facturapp_1  |  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
facturapp_1  |  at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3976)
```

My questions are:

1. why am I having such issue for just extending a simple DTO?
2. how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I could not reproduce this from a default app, it may be related to your choices when generating the app and entities.  Not sure if this matters but the docs say to use `./mvnw package -Pprod verify jib:build` which differs slightly from your commands  https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#3

Comment: I've added my yo_rc.json file. I ran the command as suggested but the result is still the same. BTW: I have 50 entities, don't know if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was using a domain class as a field instead of the DTO class for Address.

The question is still why there is a memory issue when launching the app and not when the method using the faulty class is called.